# Association for the child of the child in ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, self-join

Example of data in User table
[image]

Expected result in rails console, `grandfather.grandchildren` and `grandmother.grandchildren` should return the same group of objects:

```rb
grandfather = User.first
grandfather.grandchildren
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 5, name: "father's son", father_id: 3, mother_id: nil>, #<User id: 6, name: "uncle's son", father_id: 4, mother_id: nil>]>
grandmother = User.find(2)
grandmother.grandchildren
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 5, name: "father's son", father_id: 3, mother_id: nil>, #<User id: 6, name: "uncle's son", father_id: 4, mother_id: nil>]>
```

This is my association now in User.rb model.

```rb
 has_many :children, ->(user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user.id) }, class_name: "User"
 has_many :grandchildren, through: :children, source: :children
 belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User", optional: true
 belongs_to :father, class_name: "User", optional: true
```

Output in rails console now:

```rb
irb(main):001:0> grandfather = User.first
   (0.3ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "grandfather", mother_id: nil, father_id: nil>

irb(main):002:0> grandfather.grandchildren
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users" "children_grandchildren" ON "users"."user_id" = "children_grandchildren"."id" WHERE (father_id = 1 OR mother_id = 1) /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: father_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the grandchildren from a grandparent by going through its children because it implies that their father/mother ids are equal to the grandparent, it doesn't travel through the grandchildren parents:

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "users" "children_grandchildren"
ON "users"."user_id" = "children_grandchildren"."id"
WHERE (father_id = 1 OR mother_id = 1) -- this is the grandparent id, when it should be the child parent's id
```

You can add a *callable* to the grandchildren relationship, similar to the one for `children`, but this time extracting the grandparent children ids, and using the IN clause to filter those user rows matching those ids, with their father/mother ids:

```
has_many :grandchildren,
  ->(user) { unscope(:where).where('father_id IN (:ids) OR mother_id IN (:ids)', ids: user.children.ids) },
  class_name: "User"
```

Comment: `(0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (father_id = 1 OR mother_id = 1)`
`(0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (father_id = 1 OR mother_id = 1)`
`User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (father_id IN (3,7) OR mother_id IN (3,7)) /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]`

Three queries appeared, curious to know why `SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (father_id = 1 OR mother_id = 1)` was queried twice? Is it possible to only have one query as an output? The answer works tho, thanks for this!

Comment: Yes, I noticed that @LeeRenJie, sadly, Rails has to store somewhere the records for the user children, so, it might be that. I think, that as in your previous question, if you don't really need the relationship methods added when using has_many, you can use a simple instance method.